# SQL string replace wildcard

Tags: sql, replace

I have a table X with column Y, that contains text like this:

```
Click <a href=""http://www.stackoverflow.com"">here</a> to redeem
```

I need it turned into:

```
Click <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">here</a> to redeem
```

ie. remove the extra pair of quotes

The text outside of the ""url"" may be anything.

Is it something like this?

```
Update X SET Y = REPLACE(Y, '""%""', '"%"' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`REPLACE` replaces all occurences of the 2nd parameter with the 3rd parameter:

```
update X set Y = replace(Y, '""', '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace('Click <a href=""http://www.stackoverflow.com"">here</a> to redeem','""','"')
```

I use select to check what an update is going to do before actually doing the update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace "" by ", so do it like this:

```
Update X SET Y = REPLACE(Y, '""', '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace "" by ", so do it like this:

```
Update X SET Y = REPLACE(Y, '""', '"') WHERE y LIKE '""%""';
```

Use with a dose of caution, because it will also replace text like:

```
Click <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">""here""</a> to redeem
```

into

```
Click <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">"here"</a> to redeem
```